# Family of RV is uniformly integrable iff there is $\phi$ with $\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\rightarrow\infty$ and $\sup_n E(\phi(\vert X_n\vert))<\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

I want to show that a family $(X_n)_{n\in I}$ of real-valued RVs is uniformly integrable if and only if there exists a measurable function $\varphi:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ with $\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}\infty$ and $\sup_{n\in I}E(\varphi(\lvert X_n\rvert))<\infty$.

There is a hint, which says to consider for "suitable" $(C_k)_k\subseteq\mathbb R$ the function
$$\varphi[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty], x\mapsto\sum_{k=1}^\infty (x-C_k)1_{\{x>C_k\}}.$$
This hint raises may questions for me than it answers.

We have checked two conditions for uniform integrability of a family of RVs, which are that they are (1) bounded in $L^p$ for some $p>1$, or alternatively that they (2) are dominated by an integrable RV.

On a high level, I see the relationship between the first condition and the fact that $\varphi$ grows superlinearly (in the theorem). But I can't begin to formulate a proof. Is this a good place to start? If yes what does the start look like?

Also, I can't find any use for the hint. The function doesn't even match the requirements put on $\varphi$, and I don't see what $(C_k)$ would be "suitable". Does someone see the relationship between the hint and the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the function $\varphi$ given in the hint should be well-defined: if $x\geq C_k+1$ for all $k$ then $\varphi(x)$ would be infinite hence we should have that $C_k\to\infty$.

Moreover, observe that
$$
\varphi\left(\lvert X_n\rvert\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\lvert X_n\rvert-C_k\right)\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_n\rvert>C_k\}}\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert X_n\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_n\rvert>C_k\}}
$$
hence it would be sufficient to find $C_k$ such that $C_k\to\infty$ and for each $n$,
$$
\mathbb E\left[ \lvert X_n\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_n\rvert>C_k\}}\right]\leqslant 2^{-k}.
$$