# Question about uniform integrabilty and existence of convex function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, uniform-integrability, orlicz-spaces

The following is equivalent. 
$(1) \mathscr{F}=\{f_{\alpha},\alpha\in I\}$ is uniformly integrable.
$(2) \lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\int_{[|f_{\alpha}|>\lambda|]}{|f_{\alpha}|d\mu=0},\text{ uniformly in }\alpha\in I.$
(3) There exists a convex function $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\Phi(0)=0,\Phi(-x)=\Phi(x)$ and $\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}\uparrow \infty$ as $x\uparrow \infty$ in terms of which  $$C_{1}=\sup_{\alpha}\int_{\Omega}\Phi(f_{\alpha})d\mu<\infty$$

Can someone explain what $(3)$ is saying? I mean I don't know why but I am not getting it. The existence of such convex function.

Comment: It certainly isn't obvious that (1) implies such a $\Phi$ exists. It is proved in many books, e.g. Klenke's probability theory book. I believe it is a piecewise linear function with countably many pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, (3) says that $\mathcal F$ is a bit more than bounded in $\mathbb L^1$, because $\int_{\Omega}\Phi(f_{\alpha})d\mu$ has to be bounded independently of $\alpha$ for a function $\Phi$ that growth a bit quicker than $\lvert x\rvert$ (keep in mind the examples $\varphi(x)=\lvert x\rvert^p$ for $p>1$).

The existence of such function $\Phi$ is not trivial to show, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022139/family-of-rv-is-uniformly-integrable-iff-there-is-phi-with-frac-phixx/4034250#4034250).